# How to solve second order ODE from a simplified version of the two body problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

While thinking about the motion of a particle being attracted to another massive particle  and considering that the acceleration of that particle is not constant, I found myself trying to solve this equation $\frac{d^2f(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{f(t)^2}$

This is how I got there:

$m_1$ is the mass of object 1 and $m_2$ is the mass of object 2 which we will consider to be much larger than $m_1$.

Newton's law gives us:
$F=ma$

$F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r(t)^2}$ Let r be the distance between the two bodies.

We assume here that the movement of the particle with mass $m_2$ with respect to a stationary point is negligible.

$m_1\frac{dr(t)^2}{dt^2}=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r(t)^2}$

$\frac{dr(t)^2}{dt^2}=G\frac{m_2}{r(t)^2}$

I believe that all of this is a modified version of the two-body problem. Hopefully, the solution will be slightly simpler.

This all leads us to the original question of how to solve:

$\frac{d^2f(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{f(t)^2}$

Comment: Didn't you forget a square as in $1/f(t)^2$ ? Anyway you might want to take a look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3622637/1033009)

Comment: yup my bad, thanks